# ¿Por qué Visual Studio Code me da el error "No se puede validar porque no hay ningún ejecutable PHP establecido"?

Tags: php, vscode

Acabo de moverme a Visual Studio Code. Al trabajar con PHP me salen dos mensajes, uno de información y otro de error:

> No se puede validar porque no hay ningún ejecutable PHP establecido. Use el ajuste "php.validate.executablePath" para configurar el ejecutable de PHP.
>
> PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si no tienes el ejecutable de PHP en el PATH prueba modificar esta línea en tu configuración de VSCode (puedes abrir la configuración con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "tu/ruta/a/php.exe", // ej: C:/xampp/php/php.exe
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7):

Primero desintala las extensiones que tengas de PHP en VS Code.

Para el primer mensaje: "php.validate.executablePath" . File / Preferences / settings. O solo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (coma).

El lado izquierdo pega las siguientes líneas:

```
"php.validate.enable": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.23/php.exe",
"php.validate.run": "onSave"
```

Para la ruta dependera de donde esta la carpeta php. Puede ser xamp, wamp, defrente el php descomprimido en el c.

Para el segundo error

> "PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting".

Vuelve instalara las extensiones de php para VSCode
el mismo procedimiento... pega:

```
"php.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.23/php.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberían aclarar que en la ruta al archivo ejecutable de PHP hay que usar la "/" y no la "\" que normalmente usa un sistema de archivos windows. No tienen una idea de lo útil que es aclarar poniendo énfasis en esto.

Answer (score 0):

debes cambiar la línea a "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"

con doble Barradebes cambiar la línea a "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"

con doble Barra

Comment: La respuesta está mal redactada y es errónea pues usa \ cuando debe usarse /