# No puedo ejecutar PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio, vscode, exe

Intento ejecutar PHP en Visual studio y me aparece este error

> PHP executable not found. Install PHP and add it to your PATH or set the php.debug.executablePath setting

Me lleva a settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "php.debug.executablePath": "",
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe" //aqui estaba vacio, agregue esto
                                                          //por sugerencia y me aparece el 
                                                          //error igual
}
```

Tengo estas extensiones, por si eso afecta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta es mi carpeta donde tengo php en XAMPP**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿tienes instalado el php en tu dispositivo?  Básicamente te dice que necesitas el interprete de PHP para poder ejecutarlo desde visualcode, y si no lo tienes instalado de algun modo (con el XAMPP por ejemplo) no te funcionará nunca.

Comment: Ya agregaste la ruta de la carpeta de instalación de _PHP_ a tu **path** (variables de entorno de tu PC)?.

Comment: puse esta ruta C:/xampp/php/php.exe - esta el php.exe dentro de mi xammp

Comment: Revisa esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130842/por-qu%C3%A9-visual-studio-code-me-da-el-error-no-se-puede-validar-porque-no-hay-ni), puede que alguna de las respuestas te sirva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gracias por sus sugerencias lo resolvi agregando la ruta a

"php.debug.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"